# Add nowrap to styling?

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to stop text from wrapping. How can I add the `nowrap` to the following and keep it all working?

```
html.Append("<ins style=\"background:#e6ffe6;\">").Append(text) 
                        .Append("</ins>");
```

Need to add something like this:

```
// style='white-space:nowrap; display:inline;'
```

When I add it, it messes up my styling. I think I'm adding it wrong?

```
html.Append("<ins style='white-space:nowrap; display:inline;',style=\"background:#e6ffe6;\">").Append(text) 
                            .Append("</ins>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `style` attribute twice, try the following:

```
html.Append("<ins style=\"white-space:nowrap; display:inline; background:#e6ffe6;\">")
    .Append(text) 
    .Append("</ins>");
```

However, IMO styling is best left in a CSS file. You could just set an appropriate class (or classes):

```
html.Append("<ins class=\"aClass\">")
    .Append(text) 
    .Append("</ins>");
```

And then in your CSS file:

```
.aClass {
  white-space:nowrap; 
  display:inline; 
  background:#e6ffe6;
}
```

Comment: Thanks #1 worked could not use style sheet as my project is all win forms, i'm only using web browsers to display text with pretty html :)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong `,style=`. `Style` attribute can appear only once inside the html element. You have to write style attribute all at once:

```
html.Append("<ins style='white-space:nowrap; display:inline;background:#e6ffe6;'>).Append(text) 
                        .Append("</ins>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you combine all three style attributes in a single style tag ?

```
html.Append("<ins style=\"background:#e6ffe6;white-space:nowrap; display:inline;\">").Append(text).Append("</ins>");
```